# Java | method to write a datahandler to a file takes more time than expected

Tags: java, garbage-collection, apache-camel, fileoutputstream, datahandler

I am trying to read the mails from the MS Exchange by using `camel` and getting the attachments as `DataHandler`. A `10MB` file takes around `3hrs` to write into the location.

```
File outputFile = new File(someDirectory, someFileName);
DataHandler attachment_data = destination1Attachments.get("someFileName.txt"); 

        try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile)) {
            attachment_data.writeTo(fos);  
        }
```

I have also noticed that sometimes a 6 to 7Mb file takes around 2 to 3 minutes and when another mail comes just after that it takes more time than expected.

Because of GC ?

Trying to find the exact root cause or any other method to write the data to the file.

**Update 1** :
Tried using `BufferedOutputStream` around `FileOutputSteam` as mentioned by @user207421 in the comment. No much change could find (just 1sec or little more).

Comment: Have you tried using any profiling tool to find out what exactly takes too much time?

Comment: No Pavel. We are thinking to implement one. Will update once I have done that.

Comment: You don’t need to implement a profiling tool. Just *use* an existing one.

Comment: Oh okey. @holger do you have a suggestion ?

Comment: Add a `BufferedOutputStream` around the `FileOutputStream`.

Comment: [visualvm](https://visualvm.github.io/) for example. Up to Java 8, it is even integrated into the JDK. If you have a commercial JDK build from Oracle, there’s the [flightrecorder](https://docs.oracle.com/javacomponents/jmc-5-4/jfr-runtime-guide/about.htm#JFRUH170) included. Then, there are [jprofiler](https://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/overview.html) and [eclipse mat](https://www.eclipse.org/mat/)…

Comment: Tried using `BufferedOutputStream` around `FileOutputSteam` as mentioned by @user207421 . No much change could find (just 1sec or little more).

Answer (score 1):

This could be due to the default implementation of write mechanism.

```
attachment_data.writeTo(fos);
```

If the `DataHandler.getDataSource()!=null` then this theory will work

In this method implementation 8 bytes are getting read at a time and writing into the stream. The number of read and writes are more and this might be causing the issue.

Try reading the on your own from `DataHandler.getInputStream` and write to file by increasing the read content from the input stream.

Answer (score 1):

One must assume that the object is loaded in memory or writeTo very inefficient. Hence specify the DataFlavor and inspect `attachment_data.getTransferDataFlavors()`.

```
DataFlavor flavor = new DataFlavor(InputStream.class, "application/octetstream");
try (InputStream in = (InputStream) attachment_data.getTransferData(flavor)) {
```

Some fiddling needed.